# In c language, Embedded Application, how to compare members from an Array of structure

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, while-loop, compare

I have a Memory chip that has data read by an embedded system serially. The memory device has 10 locations with each location having the following information: customerID, NumOfParts, MFGName.
Here is my version of C code I wrote for this.

IN C FILE "PartName.h"

```
    //"PartName.h"
    #ifndef PartName_H
    #define PartName_H 

    typedef UINT8 MFGName_Struct_t [10];

    typedef struct
    {
        UINT8 customerID;
        UINT8 NumOfParts;
        MFGName_Struct_t MFGName;
    }IDENT_Struct_t;

    typedef struct MFG_Struct_t
    {
        UINT8 <some other variable>;        
        UINT8 <some other variable>;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident1;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident2;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident3;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident4;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident5;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident6;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident7;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident8;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident9;
        IDENT_Struct_t Ident10; 
    } MFG_Struct_t;

    #endif
```

IN C FILE "HighNum.c"

```
    //"HighNum.c"
    #include "PartName.h"
    static MFG_Struct_t  MFG; 
    UINT8 HighNum(void)
   {
     //UINT8 i;
       UINT8 highestNum = 0;
     //for (i = 0;(i < 10);i++) 

       if (MFG.Ident1.NumOfParts > MFG.Ident2.NumOfParts)
       {
           highestNum = MFG.Ident1.NumOfParts;
       }
       if (MFG.Ident2.NumOfParts > MFG.Ident3.NumOfParts)
       {
           highestNum = MFG.Ident2.NumOfParts;
       }
       if (MFG.Ident3.NumOfParts > MFG.Ident4.NumOfParts)
       {
           highestNum = MFG.Ident3.NumOfParts;
       }
       if (MFG.Ident4.NumOfParts > MFG.Ident5.NumOfParts)
       {
           highestNum = MFG.Ident4.NumOfParts;
       }
       <and so on>      
     return highestNum;
   }
```

How can this be done more efficient in C? using for statements or While statements? I thought about concatenating the number portion and cycling through the variables...

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your structure to this:

```
#define IDENT_SIZE         10
typedef struct MFG_Struct_t
{
    UINT8 <some other variable>;        
    UINT8 <some other variable>;
    IDENT_Struct_t Ident[IDENT_SIZE];
} MFG_Struct_t;
```

Then you can do this:

```
size_t i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < IDENT_SIZE; i++) {
     if (MFG.Ident[i].NumOfParts > highestNum) {
           highestNum = MFG.Ident[i].NumOfParts;
     }
}
```

Comment: size_t is a type? I catch the drift... the idea is to make an array os the variable you are trying to compare. For some reason the idea of concatenation somehow doesn't feel right for type of problem.

Comment: size_t is C standard type. As from my understanding, you want variable length of array? If so, use `dynamic memory allocation` instead. I can update answer if you want dynamic length of `Ident` fields in `MFG` structure.

Comment: It would be good if you could show in addition to this answer the dynamic memory Allocation solution also for completeness of this thread.

Comment: But you mentioned in the post that you have 10 fixed places in your embedded system, which means you might don't need dynamic allocation which is not part of this topic

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following code can help you:

```
typedef struct MFG_Struct_t
{
    UINT8 <some other variable>;        
    UINT8 <some other variable>;
    IDENT_Struct_t Idents[10];
} MFG_Struct_t;

typedef enum _Idents
{
    Ident1 = 0,
    Ident2,
    Ident3,
    Ident4,
    Ident5,
    Ident6,
    Ident7,
    Ident8,
    Ident9,
    Ident10,
} IdentType;


   if (MFG.Idents[Ident1].NumOfParts > MFG.Idents[Ident2].NumOfParts)
   {
       highestNum = MFG.Idents[Ident1].NumOfParts;
   }


// or
for (index = Ident1; index < Ident10; index ++)
{
    if (MFG.Idents[index].NumOfParts > MFG.Idents[index +1].NumOfParts)
    {
        //......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the structure to put the 10 "Ident" values in an array, then use a for-loop to test your values:

```
typedef struct MFG_Struct_t
{
    UINT8 <some other variable>;        
    UINT8 <some other variable>;
    IDENT_Struct_t Ident[10];
} MFG_Struct_t;
    :
    :
UINT8 HighNum(void) {
    UINT8 i, highestNum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (MFG.Ident[i].NumOfParts > MFG.Ident[i+1].NumOfParts) {
            highestNum = MFG.Ident[i].NumOfParts;
        }
    }
    return highestNum;
}
```

or, better yet... change the HighNum function to be more efficient, as follows:

```
UINT8 HighNum(void) {
    UINT8 i, highestNum = MFG.Ident[0].NumOfParts;

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (MFG.Ident[i].NumOfParts > highestNum) {
            highestNum = MFG.Ident[i].NumOfParts;
        }
    }
    return highestNum;
}
```

Comment: I like the efficient part, and that is the intent here.